# How to get CPU usage at a specific point in time with PromQL

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, metrics, promql, metrics-server

I currently have these three PromQL queries:

CPU Sum:

```
curl -s -G "http://10.192.248.10:30000/api/v1/query" --data-urlencode "query=sum_over_time(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod='f5ingress-f5ingress-55ff78b955-vqxch', namespace='arka-ingress'}[10m])" | jq
```

CPU Average:

```
curl -s -G "http://10.192.248.10:30000/api/v1/query" --data-urlencode "query=avg_over_time(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod='f5ingress-f5ingress-55ff78b955-vqxch', namespace='arka-ingress'}[10m])" | jq
```

CPU Datapoints:

```
curl -s -G "http://10.192.248.10:30000/api/v1/query" --data-urlencode "query=container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{pod='f5ingress-f5ingress-55ff78b955-vqxch', namespace='arka-ingress'}[10m]" | jq
```

I technically have two questions:

- For the 'CPU Datapoints' query, how can I pass in the 'step' parameter? For example, in the query it uses a time window of 10m, how can I specify how many datapoints I want the function to return in that window?
- How can I get the CPU usage at a specific point in time? The only CPU query I see in PromQL is container_cpu_usage_seconds_total. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use e.g. `[10m:1m]` to give a per-1-minute measurement over the 10-minute period, i.e. 10 measurements.

Comment: @DazWilkin That worked, thank you. Does anyone know how to get CPU usage (or really any metric) at a specific time?

Comment: Use the [@ modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#modifier)

Comment: @DazWilkin When I run this query for example:
`curl -s -G "http://10.192.248.10:30000/api/v1/query" --data-urlencode "query=http_requests_total[10m:5m] @ 1685665200" | jq`

it returns this:
`"values": [[1685664600, "405011"], [1685664900, "405124"], [1685665200, "405244"]]`

Shouldn't it only return the values that match the timestamp: 1685665200?

Comment: No, because you specify `[10m:5m]` the `@` defines the end time for the range. I encourage you to read the documentation at the link I provided.

Comment: @DazWilkin, why `@` and not [`time` query parameter](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-queries)?

Comment: And for the first question `/api/v1/query_range` with `steps` parameter should do it too.

Answer (score 0):

The `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` metric shows cumulative CPU time used by the given `container` since the start of `cadvisor` - see [these docs](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/storage/prometheus.md#prometheus-container-metrics).

This is so called [counter metric type](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#counter).

If you want obtaining the real CPU usage at the given time, then use [rate()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate) function. For example, the following command would return the average CPU usage over the last 5 minutes for every running container at the given [timestamp](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) `1685665200`:

```
curl -G http://10.192.248.10:30000/api/v1/query --data-urlencode 'time=1685665200' --data-urlencode 'query=rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[5m])'
```

This command sends the query to [instant query API](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#instant-query) provided by Prometheus. This API returns a single calculated point at the given `time` per each [time series](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#time-series), which match the given [filter](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#filtering).

If you need obtaining multiple calculated points per each matching time series  on the given time range, then take a look at [range query API](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#range-query).